# cosine of rational multiples of Pi take values of equal difference

Tags: polynomials, trigonometric-polynomials

In my physics research I came across a mathematical proposition (translated into the mathematical language from the physical problem) that I feel to be true, and would like to prove it:

**Proposition: Consider the function $f(m)=\cos(\frac{2m+1}{N}\pi)$ where the integer $m$ satisfies $0\leq m<N$ and the integer $N>2$. The situation $f(m_1)-f(m_2)=f(m_2)-f(m_3)$ while $f(m_1)>f(m_2)>f(m_3)$ can happen if and only if $\frac{2m_2+1}{N}=\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{2m_2+1}{N}=\frac{3}{2}$.**

The if part is very simple. However I have not been able to prove the only if part. Without loss of generality it should be sufficient to consider only the case where $\frac{2m_i+1}{N}\pi\leq \pi$ because the cosine function is symmetric w.r.t $\pi$. If I restrict $m_1-m_2=m_2-m_3$ then I can show the proposition is true only if $\frac{2m_2+1}{N}=\frac{1}{2}$. Without the restriction however I'm having no luck.

The proposition probably relies on the fact that all the $m$'s and $N$ are integers. One idea I have tried is to notice that if $\theta=\frac{2m+1}{N}$ then $\cos(N\theta)=-1$ and there is a formula to expand $\cos(N\theta)$ into a polynomial $p_N(\cos(\theta))$ of $\cos(\theta)$, hence $f(m_1)$, $f(m_2)$ and $f(m_3)$ are all roots of the equation $p_N(\cos(\theta))$+1=0. But I haven't been able to proceed from there.

Of course the proposition may not be true after all despite my intuition, but if then it'd be nice to find out for which $N$ it fails. It certainly is true for $N\leq 8$ since I have calculated all solutions. Either way the proposition would have real physical consequences.

Comment: @MarkSapir so what?

Comment: Yes, but OP asks about the case when $m_1-m_2\ne m_2-m_3$

Comment: This is certainly true if $N$ is prime, or more generally if $\phi(N)>\frac 56N$, where $\phi$ is the Euler phi-function, since a relation of the type you're interested in  gives rise to a polynomial with integer coefficients satisfied by $e^{2\pi i/N}$ of degree at most $5N/6$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: You are right!

Comment: @AnthonyQuas After some learning in the Euler phi-function, I cannot see how it is related to the current problem in the way Anthony proposed, could you please elaborate? Thank you very much!

Comment: If $\zeta$ is a primitive $N$th root of unity, its minimal polynomial over the rationals is the $N$th cyclotomic polynomial, $\Phi_N$. This of degree $\phi(N)$. Any rational polynomial that has $\zeta$ as a root is a multiple of $\Phi_N$. If your equation is satisfied, it gives rise to an equation in $\zeta$ with rational coefficients of degree at most $5N/6$ satisfied by $\zeta$. This is a contradiction if $\phi(N)>5N/6$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I have problem to see "If your equation is satisfied, it gives rise to an equation in $\zeta$ with rational coefficients of degree at most 5N/6 satisfied by $\zeta$." What is the primitive Nth root of unity in the current problem? Maybe you mean converting the cosines into the Euler complex form? But then where does the 5N/6 come from? Also the Euler formula would give several different roots of unity, not just a single $\zeta$. Could you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof uses the reference suggested by Felipe Voloch in a comment below the answer provided by Anthony Quas:

In Conway and Jones, Acta Arith. XXX (1976) 229-240, Theorem 7 (abbreviated to CJ7 in the following discussions) states that:

Suppose we have at most four distinct rational multiples of $\pi$ lying strictly between 0 and $\pi/2$ for which some rational linear combination of their cosines is rational but no proper subset has this property. Then the appropriate linear combination is proportional to one from the following list:
    $\cos \pi/3 =1/2$,
    $-\cos \phi+\cos(\pi/3-\phi)+\cos(\pi/3+\phi)=0$,
    $\cos \pi/5-\cos 2\pi/5=1/2$,
    $\cos \pi/7-\cos 2\pi/7+\cos 3\pi/7=1/2$,
    $\cos \pi/5-\cos \pi/15+\cos 4\pi/15=1/2$,
    $-\cos 2\pi/5+\cos 2\pi/15-\cos 7\pi/15=1/2$,
    $\cos \pi/7+\cos 3\pi/7-\cos \pi/21+\cos 8\pi/21=1/2$,
    $\cos \pi/7-\cos 2\pi/7+\cos 2\pi/21-\cos 5\pi/21=1/2$,
    $-\cos 2\pi/7+\cos 3\pi/7+\cos 4\pi/21+\cos 10\pi/21=1/2$,
    $-\cos \pi/15+\cos 2\pi/15+\cos 4\pi/15-\cos 7\pi/15=1/2$,

In the current problem we want to find the conditions for $\cos(\frac{2m_1+1}{N}\pi)+\cos(\frac{2m_3+1}{N}\pi)-2\cos(\frac{2m_2+1}{N}\pi)=0$ which for the moment can be written as $\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_3-2\cos\theta_2=0$, where $0<\theta_i\leq \pi$.

Before we can use CJ7, we need to first consider the case when $\theta_1=\pi$ or $\theta_2=\pi$. If $\theta_1=\pi$, $\cos\theta_3-2\cos\theta_2=1$, which is not possible by CJ7 if none of $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ is $\pi/2$. If indeed we allow $\theta_3=\pi/2$ and $\theta_2=2\pi/3$ the equation is satisfied. However in our original problem $\theta_i=\frac{2m_i+1}{N}\pi$, and there is no integers of $N$ and $m_i$ that can make both $\theta_3=\pi/2$ and $\theta_1=\pi$, so this is not an option. On the other hand if If $\theta_2=\pi$, $\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_3=-2$, simply impossible.

So now we consider the case none of the three angles is $\pi$. Again we cannot use CJ7 unless we first exclude the case when one of them is $\pi/2$. Suppose $\theta_1=\pi/2$ then $\cos\theta_3-2\cos\theta_2=0$ which is not possible by CJ7. On the other hand if $\theta_2=\pi/2$ then $\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_3=0$, which is impossible by CJ7 if $\theta_1$ and $\theta_3$ are distinct as defined in CJ7. If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_3$ are allowed to be antisymmetric pairs w.r.t. $\pi/2$ CJ7 doesn't apply and the sum is 0. Note that this case is just the one we originally proposed.

Now suppose none of the three angles is either $\pi$ or $\pi/2$, then if they are all distinct as defined by CJ7, we know $\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_3-2\cos\theta_2$ cannot be rational, and hence cannot be 0. If two of them are antisymmetric pairs w.r.t. $\pi/2$ then either $-2\cos\theta_2=0$ or $\cos\theta_1+3\cos\theta_3=0$, which we know are impossible by CJ7.

To summary, for all the cases where CJ7 does not apply, we have shown that the equality to zero is satisfied if and only if $\theta_2=\pi/2$ and $\theta_1$ and $\theta_3$ are antisymmetric pairs w.r.t. $\pi/2$. For the cases where CJ7 applies, we have shown that the equality to zero is never possible. Hence our original proposition is true.

Comment: Does accepting an answer prevent people from commenting further? I will un-accept it then because I'd like it to be discussed and criticized.

Comment: Accepting an answer doesn't stop anyone from doing anything. It may discourage some people from looking at the question, since they figure there's nothing they can add – but it may encourage some people to look at the question, since they figure they can learn something. Anyway, accepting an answer is generally considered a good thing to do, once OP finds an answer acceptable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok I see! Yea since it is my own answer so I obviously think it is a good answer, but I figure maybe I should wait for people to criticize it a little bit before I accept it. If by the end of tomorrow nobody finds anything wrong about it I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/N}$ and $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/(2N)}$. Your assumption was $\Re(\alpha(\zeta^{m_3}-2\zeta^{m_2}+\zeta^{m_1}))=0$. This is equivalent to $\alpha(\zeta^{m_3}-2\zeta^{m_2}+\zeta^{m_1}))+\bar\alpha(\zeta^{-m_3}-2\zeta^{-m_2}+\zeta^{-m_1})=0$. Multiplying by $\bar\alpha$ and using the fact that $\alpha^2=\zeta$, you get $\zeta^{m_3}-2\zeta^{m_2}+\zeta^{m_1}+\zeta^{N-m_3-1}-2\zeta^{N-m_2-1}+\zeta^{N-m_1-1}=0$. You can multiply this equation by any power of $\zeta$ that you want (again using $\zeta^N=1$) to ensure that any term you want becomes the constant term. Since there are 6 powers of $\zeta$ arranged around the circle, if you set the power that immediately follows the longest gap to be the constant term, the polynomial you arrive at has degree at most $5N/6$.

On the other hand, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $\Phi_N$, the $N$th cyclotomic polynomial, which has degree $\phi(N)$. The polynomial that we arrived at above must be a multiple of $\Phi_N$. This is impossible if $\phi(N)>5N/6$ (which is true if $N$ is prime, and for infinitely many other numbers).

Comment: Do you mean "which is true if $N$ is prime and $N>5\,$"? I think that $\phi(5)=4<\frac{5}{6}\cdot 5$.

Comment: I suppose so! Since the OP already dealt with $N\le 8$, I wasn't too worried about that case.

Comment: I am stuck at the last step: " if you set the power that immediately follows the longest gap to be the constant term, the polynomial you arrive at has degree at most 5N/6." Otherwise this is a very nice proof for the numbers that satisfy $\phi(N)>5N/6$. I will think more along this line to see if there can be a proof or counter proof for non-primes.

Comment: Now that's been reduced to a sum of eight roots of unity, it suffices to apply theorem 6 of Conway and Jones, Acta Arith. XXX (1976) 229-240 to find all solutions.

Comment: I'll illustrate my answer by an example. Let $N=67$ and imagine that $\zeta^6 - 2\zeta^{13}+\zeta^{18}+\zeta^{60}-2\zeta^{53}+\zeta^{48}=0$. There are non-zero coefficients in the 6th, 13th, 18th, 48th, 53rd and 60th powers of $\zeta$. The gap between 60th and 6th powers is 13 (going around the circle), which is smaller than the gap between the 18th and 48th. , so I'll multiply the entire equation by $\zeta^{-48}=\zeta^{19}$ to obtain $1-2\zeta^5+\zeta^{12}+\zeta^{25}-2\zeta^{32}+\zeta^{37}=0$. The degree of this polynomial is less than $5N/6$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I woke up this morning and suddenly understood your statement! I also noticed that these 6 powers are not randomly distributed on the circle, so maybe the 5N/6 limit can be further refined. I will also check Felipe's reference to see if it helps. Your answer is a significant progress and thank you very much!

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Also the coefficients of the polynomial are not random, so the limit on the degree may be refined further.

Comment: Observing $\zeta^{m_3}-2\zeta^{m_2}+\zeta^{m_1}+\zeta^{N-m_3-1}-2\zeta^{N-m_2-1}+\zeta^{N-m_1-1}=0$, the last three terms are no longer conjugates of the first three, but shifted by -1 in the power, so it is "unlikely" that each term such as $\zeta^{m_3}$ can still cancel with $\zeta^{N-m_3-1}$. On the other hand the terms associated with the $m_2$'s have a different coefficient, i.e. 2, than the rest, so they have to cancel each other. To be continued

Comment: continued: Hence we need to have $\zeta^{m_3}$ cancel with $\zeta^{N-m_1-1}$ and $\zeta^{m_1}$ cancel with $\zeta^{N-m_3-1}$ while $2\zeta^{m_2}$ cancels with $2\zeta^{N-m_2-1}$. Indeed, it is pretty hard to satisfy all these conditions, and when $m_1-m_2=m_2-m_3$ and $\frac{2m_2+1}{N}=\frac{1}{2}$ as in my original idea, these conditions are satisfied and we can achieve zero for the polynomial. This is kind of a loose argument but maybe there is a way to make the loose statement strict ...

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Felipe has suggested a reference and it looks promising. I will read it but as a physicist I will need additional time to learn and digest the mathematics there.